# Building Python Dictionaries Dynamically Does Not Returns the Desired Result

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a class `ResourcesBuilder` in Python 3.7 that:

- takes some JSON data:

  - `accounts`: a dictionary & list of parent and child accounts
  - `service`: some string identifier
  - `data`: could be either dictionary, list or string
- dynamically builds a nested dictionary with the input data and returns it as JSON

```py
import json


class ResourcesBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_account = {}
        self.accounts = {}

    def build(self, parent_account, child_account, service, data):
        self.parent_account[child_account] = {service: data}
        self.accounts[parent_account] = self.parent_account


def main():
    accounts = json.loads('{"p_acc_1": ["c_acc_1a", "c_acc_1b"], "p_acc_2": ["c_acc_2a", "c_acc_2b"]}')
    service = 'test_service'
    builder = ResourcesBuilder()
    for parent_account in accounts:
        for a_account in accounts[parent_account]:
            data = 'test_data'
            builder.build(parent_account, a_account, service, data)
    print(json.dumps(builder.accounts, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When run, the above code currently returns:

```json
## CURRENT OUTCOME
{
    "p_acc_1": {
        "c_acc_1a": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        },
        "c_acc_1b": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        },
        "c_acc_2a": {
            "test_service": "test_data"    <--- this should not be returned
        },
        "c_acc_2b": {
            "test_service": "test_data"    <--- this should not be returned
        }
    },
    "p_acc_2": {
        "c_acc_1a": {
            "test_service": "test_data"    <--- this should not be returned
        },
        "c_acc_1b": {
            "test_service": "test_data"    <--- this should not be returned
        },
        "c_acc_2a": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        },
        "c_acc_2b": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it lists all the children accounts under all parent accounts instead of listing the children **only** under their respective accounts:

```json
# DESIRED OUTCOME
{
    "p_acc_1": {
        "c_acc_1a": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        },
        "c_acc_1b": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        }
    },
    "p_acc_2": {
        "c_acc_2a": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        },
        "c_acc_2b": {
            "test_service": "test_data"
        }
    }
}
```

I am starting with python so I would really appreciate how I can better achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in the second step of your `build` function you are essentially linking the whole dictionary you created back to the accounts. You only need to copy the dictionaries that are children of the parent for which you are assigning `self.accounts[parent_account]`. Since, in a `for` loop over the list of children you cannot explicitly get all the children data at once, you need to create a new function, that links the parent dictionary.

```
import json


class ResourcesBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_account = {}
        self.accounts = {}

    def build(self, parent_account, child_account, service, data):
        self.parent_account[child_account] = {service: data}

    # This function links the parent correctly
    # i.e., link only those dictionaries which are children of the
    # current parent
    def link_parent(self, parent_account, child_list):
        self.accounts[parent_account] = {k: self.parent_account[k] 
                                         for k in child_list}


def main():
    accounts = json.loads('{"p_acc_1": ["c_acc_1a", "c_acc_1b"], "p_acc_2": ["c_acc_2a", "c_acc_2b"]}')
    service = 'test_service'
    builder = ResourcesBuilder()
    for parent_account in accounts:
        for a_account in accounts[parent_account]:
            data = 'test_data'
            builder.build(parent_account, a_account, service, data)

        # Now once the children nodes have been created, link the parent
        builder.link_parent(parent_account, accounts[parent_account])
    print(json.dumps(builder.accounts, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can refer [this Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o30oxR8SovF-Kusk15ad3Jh_-QN7J0yY) with the working code for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You Almost there buddy, Just Clear Parent Account On each iteration of Parent Loop

```
import json


class ResourcesBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_account = {}
        self.accounts = {}

    def build(self, parent_account, child_account, service, data):
        self.parent_account[child_account] = {service: data}
        self.accounts[parent_account] = self.parent_account


def main():
    accounts = json.loads('{"p_acc_1": ["c_acc_1a", "c_acc_1b"], "p_acc_2": ["c_acc_2a", "c_acc_2b"]}')
    service = 'test_service'
    builder = ResourcesBuilder()
    for parent_account in accounts:
        for a_account in accounts[parent_account]:
            data = 'test_data'
            builder.build(parent_account, a_account, service, data)
        builder.parent_account = {}  ## Here I've made change
    print(json.dumps(builder.accounts, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Both** answers (Narendra and Mohammed's) are correct and helpful, and I would have chosen them both if I could as the answer :)!
Chose Narendra in the end because it is more explicit for me as a beginner.
Mohammed, sorry in case I did not end up choosing your answer based on my ignorance.

UPDATE: After looking a bit more into Mohammed's answer I decided that handles the problem more elegantly, even though it is not evident for a newbie.

Thank you **both** a lot!